# GKE networkpolicy for cloudsql_proxy

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cloud-sql-proxy

I tried to use NetworkPolicy on GKE.

My pod api has API application and cloudSql proxy

```
        image: myapi
        name: myapi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
      - command:
        - /cloud_sql_proxy
        - -instances=my-project:asia-northeast1:my-instance=tcp:3307
        - -ip_address_types=PRIVATE
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16
        name: cloudsql-proxy
```

I couldn't figure out what kind of egress rule to set. I just tried to set 127.0.0.1:3307, but it must not be; because api -> cloudsql_proxy is 127.0.0.1:3307.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    env: develop
    projectid: my-project
  name: my-networkpolicy
spec:
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 3307
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 127.0.0.1/32
```

error

> Get https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/my-project/instances/my-instance?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: dial tcp: i/o timeout

How can I set NetworkPolicy ?

※ I already figured out if there are no egress rule in NetrowkPolicy, connection worked fine

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for setting up `NetworkPolicy` here ? It should work without any. Judging by the port you use, it's MySQL instance, right ?

Comment: For security requirement, I need to set some network rule. And I thought setting NetworkPolicy is better than setting firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that UDP:53 must be added for cloudsql-proxy

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    env: develop
    projectid: my-project
  name: my-networkpolicy
spec:
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
---
```

Comment: I am just trying the same and its not working for me. Are you sure it worked for you? There is no pod selector.